# How do I display different table from 1 table? Like each table has unique code

Tags: php, html, mysqli

This are my db table:
[image: This are my db table]

But my query only get 1 row for each table like this:

[image: like this]

As you can see, there are 2 tables for 1003 because it has 2 rows. It should be only one (1) table of 1003 with 2 rows. How do I fix this? EXPECTED RESULT:

[image: EXPECTED RESULT]

```
            // Attempt select query execution
            $query = "SELECT model, brand_code FROM smartphone GROUP BY model";
            if($result = mysqli_query($db, $query))
            {
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                    ?>
                    <?php echo $row["brand_code"]?>
                    <table id="table_stock" class="">
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>Model</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <td><?php echo $row["model"]?></td>
                          </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table><br>
                    <?php 
                    }
                    /// Free result
                    mysqli_free_result($result);
                } 
                else
                {
                    echo "<td class='no_record' colspan='7'>No records found.</td>";
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
             }
```

Comment: Just `tr` with model must be inside `mysqli_fetch_array`, other table structure outside

Comment: Can you show me? I have been doing this atleast a week and stackoverflow is my last option after some research and etc. Im new to programming tho

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you need additional loop. Also in the first query you need to use group by codes.

```
        $query = "SELECT model, brand_code FROM smartphone GROUP BY brand_code";
        if($result = mysqli_query($db, $query))
        {
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
 ?>
                <?php echo $row["brand_code"]?>
                <table id="table_stock" class="">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Model</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

 <?php
                    if ($result1 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT DISTINCT model, brand_code FROM smartphone WHERE brand_code={$row["brand_code"]}")) 
                    {
                       while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
                       {                               
                             // get count for each model within brand_code
                             $cnt = ($result2 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM smartphone WHERE brand_code={$row["brand_code"]} AND model='{$row1["model"]}'")) && ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) ? $row2["cnt"] : "---";
                ?>
                      <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $row1["model"] ({$cnt})?></td>
                      </tr>
                <?php 
                      }
                     mysqli_free_result($result1);
                  }
 ?>
                  </tbody>
                </table><br>
 <?php
               }

                /// Free result
                mysqli_free_result($result);
            } 
            else
            {
                echo "<td class='no_record' colspan='7'>No records found.</td>";
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
         }
```

Comment: tried this but it only display all models in 1 table

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Yes, this is what I expected. Thank you very much sir! I will learn more for sure. But how do I keep the same model to be distinct row? See updated question on "expected result"

Comment: just add DISTINCT to sql query. see updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, sir! I will vote once I gain 15 reputations

Comment: Sir, if I could ask one more question. How do we count row each of the model after distinct?

Comment: just modify query `SELECT DISTINCT model, brand_code FROM smartphone ....` to `SELECT DISTINCT model, brand_code, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM smartphone .....` and after executing `$row1["cnt"]`  will contain count

Comment: I tried sir but only return total row of each brand_code not model. Like for table 1003, Galaxy Z return 2 and Galaxy S21 also return 2 whereas both model should be 1 since both model only have 1 row each in database. It would be nice if you can update the answer above 

Comment: updated. look at commented code

Comment: That was complicated. Thank you very much, sir! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 5 problems here,

*[edit: problem 1 removed & changed sample based on extended answer]*

---

Inside your `while { ... }` loop, you're printing an entire table, when you should only be printing the `<tr>...</tr>` part there. This is what causes additional table(s).

---

And 3rd problem: your "no_record" line is a loose `<td>`. Not only isn't it inside the table (which is covered in problem #2), it's also not wrapped with a `<tr>`.

---

4th problem: You're randomly printing the `echo $row["brand_code"]` outside of the table.

---

5th problem: you're printing raw data from the database as if it is valid html, it more than likely is not. it has to be probably encoded with `htmlentities`/`htmlspecialchars`.

---

Quick & dirty fixed version:

```
function tableOpen($row) {
    printf(  '<h1>%s</h1>', htmlentities($row["brand_code"]) );
    echo '<table id="table_stock" class="">';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Model</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';
}
function tableClose() {
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table><br>';
}
// Attempt select query execution
$query = "SELECT model, brand_code FROM smartphone ORDER BY brand_code";
$lastBrand = null;
if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        if ($lastBrand !== $row["brand_code"] && !is_null($lastBrand)) tableClose();
        if ($lastBrand !== $row["brand_code"]) tableOpen($row);
        $lastBrand = $row["brand_code"];
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo   '<tr>';
            printf(  '<td>%s</td>', htmlentities($row["model"]) );
            echo   '</tr>';
        }
        tableClose();
        /// Free result
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else {
        echo '<p class="no_record">No records found.</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Not able to execute \$query: <br>" . htmlentities($query) . '<br>' . htmlentities(mysqli_error($link));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out sir. I will keep your replies to improve myself. But this isn't my expected result. I have updated the expected result in my question.

Comment: (updated) I see, yea that is very different; i've updated the code above based on your expected output.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! I will vote once I gain the privileged.